# The gang's all here

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, movies

> Of us there are three
>   one of which is part tree;
>   The other one you should not fear,
>   but it will make you burst in tears;
>   As for the last one, and there is no bluffing,
>   that's the one you'll never see coming.

What are the members of the gang?

Comment: I have a feeling your remark about a fantasy tag already gave the answer away a bit.

Comment: @JAD i knew it was going to make the riddle extremly easy, but i thought it was really needed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is it

> The three deathly hallows

Of us there are three

> There are three of them

one of which is part tree;

> The elder wand is made up of wood from an elder tree

The other one you should not fear,
but it will make you burst in tears;

> The resurrection stone brings back people from the dead, hence though it will not hurt you therefore no reason to fear it, it with cause strong emotional feelings of intense happiness or sadness, both usually accompanied with tears.

As for the last one, and there is no bluffing,
that's the one you'll never see coming.

> The invisibility cloak renders its user invisible, hence you'll not see it coming.

Comment: Exactly the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

I know this already has been answered, but I was thinking about:

> The three characters in Wizard of Oz

one of which is part tree;

> Some parts of The Scarecrow are made out of tree, right?

The other one you should not fear,
but it will make you burst in tears;

> "The Tin Woodman, who asks the Wizard for a heart." That just makes us cry, doesn't it?

As for the last one, and there is no bluffing,
that's the one you'll never see coming.

> "The Cowardly Lion" Lions are known to attack their prey without them seeing it coming.

Comment: wow, i really like this approach, nice work

Answer (score 6):

Is it.....

> An onion, a chopping board and a knife?

*One of which is part tree:*

> A chopping board is traditionally made of wood, sometimes with a handle made of another material (part tree, or part of a tree).

*The other one you should not fear,
but it will make you burst in tears:*

> Onions make you cry when you cut them.

*As for the last one, and there is no bluffing,
that's the one you'll never see coming:*

> Unlike the onion which isn't to be feared, a knife (as a weapon) certainly is, and can be concealed (hence you may not see it coming)

*"The gang's all here":*

> These are three items that would be collected together, to chop an onion!

Comment: Very nice answer, but this is not the gang we are looking for!

Comment: But this does not show 3 gang members!

Comment: @DeadManWalking board, knife, onion. I'll admit the answer muddied things up a bit pointing out that the knife handle could be made of wood as well (thus lumping it in with the first member), but I'm pretty sure the intent was that the knife is the third member.

Comment: @DoktorJ What is the name of the gang??? HUH???

Comment: @DeadManWalking The OP didn't ask for the name of the gang when I submitted my answer, that was a later edit. As my answer was not the correct one in the end I'll just let it stand.

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but i think this could fit as well:

> are the members of the gang paper, scissor and rock?

*Of us there are three*

> they are indeed three

*one of which is part tree*

> Paper comes from trees

*The other one you should not fear,
but it will make you burst in tears*

> There's no actual reason to fear a pair of scissors, but you could hurt your self pretty badly with it

*As for the last one, and there is no bluffing,
that's the one you'll never see coming*

> Not really sure about this and this is really streched, but it kinda remids me of Harry Potter when Harry hits himself with a rock to alert himself of the people coming to hagrid's place (Harry Potter and the prisoner of Azkaban)